# Is "well within" an idiomatic expression

Tags: idiomatic-language

In some not-so-formal techical writing of mine I've been argued that something like

"Your requirement is **well within** our system specification"

with the supposed meaning that "what you require to be done is easily achievable by our equipment"
is not clearly if not at all understandable.

So, recapping the question is

"Is "well within" idiomatic and clear in the contest outlined above?

Comment: ***Well*** is just an optional intensifier in the cited context. It could just as well/easily be replaced by *Your requirement is **easily** within our system specification* (or better, imho, ***...falls** well/easily within...*). Or it could be omitted, without really changing anything much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's idiomatic.
It implies that not only is something within requirements but within by a notable margin.

From [Cambridge Dictionary - within](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/within)

> **inside the limits of something, for example the law or a set of rules, and allowed by it:**
> I was acting within the law (= legally).
> She managed to complete her last film well within budget.